# subtlety around minimisation of expectation of an r.v

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm attempting the following questions

[image]

The first question is fine. However i feel like things get interesting in the second question. Now i'm not too familiar with things like functionals but this kind of approach made sense to me the most because i feel as simplified solutions i have found overlook a subtlety and just say c) follows from b) by essentially noticing $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|X)) = \mathbb{E}(Y)$. As far as i'm aware $\mathbb{E}((Y-f(X))^2|X)$ returns a random variable and not a value in $\mathbb{R}$. Where as $\mathbb{E}(Y-f(X))^2$ returns a value in $\mathbb{R}$. If this is correct then what does it mean to minimise the random variable in b. ?

Well we can deduce that $\mathbb{E}((Y-f(x))^2|X) = (f(x) - \mathbb{E}(Y|X))^2 - (\mathbb{E}(Y|X))^2 + E(Y^2|X)$. Now if we let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the space of functions we want $f' \in \mathcal{F}$ that satisfies
$(f'(x) - \mathbb{E}(Y|X))^2 - (\mathbb{E}(Y|X))^2 + E(Y^2|X) \leq (f(x) - \mathbb{E}(Y|X))^2 - (\mathbb{E}(Y|X))^2 + E(Y^2|X)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$. Now clearly $f'(x) = \mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ satisfies this as the square term is then $0$.

$\textbf{Key Result}$: So let the random variable $F' =(f'(x) - \mathbb{E}(Y|X))^2 - (\mathbb{E}(Y|X))^2 + E(Y^2|X)$ where $f'(x) = \mathbb{E}(Y|X)$
and let the random variable
$F = (f(x) - \mathbb{E}(Y|X))^2 - (\mathbb{E}(Y|X))^2 + E(Y^2|X)$ where $f$ is any function in $\mathcal{F}$ then i know it's always the case that $F' \leq F$

Now i can use the key result for part c. I know that $\mathbb{E}(Y-f(x))^2 = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}((Y-f(x))|X)$. For two random variables $X, Y$ its trivial that if $X \leq Y \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X) \leq \mathbb{E}(Y)$. So again considering the space of functions $\mathcal{F}$. Let $f' = \mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ and obtain $F'$ from $f'$ and $F$ from any other $f$ like we did before. Then i know that $F' \leq F$ and thus $\mathbb{E}(F') \leq \mathbb{E}(F)$. So i can conclude that to minimize $(Y- f(X))^2$ we require $f(x) = \mathbb{E}(Y|X)$.

Firstly is my reasoning correct? If it is correct have i over complicated it and is there a simpler solution? Thanks.

Comment: The notation $f'(x) = E[Y|X]$ does not quite make sense.  The left-hand-side seems to be a function of $x$ while the right is a random variable.  It may also help to use $g$, as $f'$ looks like a derivative.

Comment: But $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ is a function of $X$? Why does the notation f(X) = X^2 for example not make sense for r.v? Also does my intuition seem to work ? Thanks!

Comment: If $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function, and if $X$ is a random variable, then $h(X)$ is another random variable. Indeed $E[Y|X]$ is a random variable and it can indeed be viewed as a pure function of $X$ as follows: Define $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  by $h(x) = E[Y|X=x]$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $E[Y|X]=h(X)$.

Comment: Your approach bears some resemblance to that of my answer below. However, I could not follow your work due to things like: The $X$ versus $x$ issue; the fact that your "Well we can deduce" seems to start in the middle of the derivation and skips the most important step (**it is not a good idea to skip the most important step**); some typos such as redefining $f'(x)=E[Y|X]^2$ versus $f'(x) = E[Y|X]$; overall your approach seems overly complex. Note that my answer ends with "operate" that (hopefully) allows you to perform the most important step to achieve your own "Aha!" moment.

Comment: A couple of questions around your answer. Firstly $c$ is a constant and $f$ is a function so the situation is different. In addition $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ a different right? As one is a number and the other a function of $X$. I was trying to capture this kind of subtly in my response.  Your approach also makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition is that $E[(Y-c)^2|X=x]$ is minimized over all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ in the same way as in part (a), except now we condition on a world in which $X=x$.

---

Another approach is to note
\begin{align}
(Y-f(X))^2 &= (Y-E[Y|X])^2 + (E[Y|X]-f(X))^2 \\
& \quad + \underbrace{2(Y-E[Y|X])(E[Y|X]-f(X))}_{\mbox{operate}}
\end{align}
and take conditional expectations given $X$, operate on the third term.